# JavaScript array has length, but I can't get values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make my [d3 wordcloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/) responsive. I have initialized the cloud like this:

```
var cloud = d3.layout.cloud()
    .rotate(0)
    .font("Open Sans, sans-serif")
    .fontWeight(600)
    .fontSize(d => {
        var size = d.size;
        return size;
    })
    .on("end", (words: any[]) => {
        this.text = this.vis.selectAll("text").data(words); // this.vis is the "g" node appended to the svg
        var b = this.text.enter().append("text");
        b.style("font-size", function (d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .style("fill", (d: any) => "#272C2F")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function (d) { return d.text; });
    });
```

When the screen size changes I update it using this:

```
this.cloud.stop();
this.cloud.size([this.$view.offsetWidth, this.$view.offsetHeight]); // this.$view.offsetWidth and this.$view.offsetWidth call the width and height of the view
this.cloud.words(newlist); // newlist is an array with objects like this { text: string; count: number }
```

This works perfect the first time it is run. but then it does nothing. When I look in the code of d3 I see it has problems in this method:

```
d3_selection_enterPrototype.select = function(selector) {
    var subgroups = [], subgroup, subnode, upgroup, group, node;
    for (var j = -1, m = this.length; ++j < m; ) {
        upgroup = (group = this[j]).update;
        subgroups.push(subgroup = []);
        subgroup.parentNode = group.parentNode;
        for (var i = -1, n = group.length; ++i < n; ) {
            if (node = group[i]) {
                subgroup.push(upgroup[i] = subnode = selector.call(group.parentNode, node.__data__, i, j));
                subnode.__data__ = node.__data__;
            } else {
                subgroup.push(null);
            }
        }
    }
    return d3_selection(subgroups);
};
```

If I call 'this' the first time, you can see it is an array and I can call those values inside the array. However when I run it again (after resizing my screen) the values are suddenly gone, even though the array still has the same length.

[image: result of console window when calling 'this']

Is this a bug in d3? Or am I updating the cloud wrong?

Comment: Two dimensional array

Comment: In JavaScript, you can define the length of the array and don't supply the elements in it. Both `var bla = new Array(165)` and `var bla = []; bla.length = 165` will do the same ;)

Comment: D3 doesn't have a cloud layout, this is a third party plugin. If the problem lies in this plugin's code (and I'm not saying it does), you'll have to check its internals, not D3 internals.